# What's the point of these two java methods defining the same variables

Tags: java

I'm new to Java & am looking through a library but I'm a bit confused by two methods:

```
public class Complex {

    /** The real part of a complex number. */
    private double real;

    /** The imaginary part of a complex number. */
    private double imaginary;

    public void divideComplex(Complex a, Complex b) {
      this.real = a.real * b.real + a.imaginary * b.imaginary;
      this.imaginary = a.imaginary * b.real - a.real * b.imaginary;
      this.scaleComplex(this, b.squaredMagnitudeComplex());
    }

    public void scaleComplex(Complex a, double b) {
      this.real = a.real / b;
      this.imaginary = a.imaginary / b;
    }

}
```

Am I missing something here or couldn't `divideComplex` do this instead:

```
    public void divideComplex(Complex a, Complex b) {
      Complex newComplex = new Complex { 
        val real = this.real = a.real * b.real + a.imaginary * b.imaginary;
        val imaginary = this.imaginary = a.imaginary * b.real - a.real * b.imaginary;
      }
      this.scaleComplex(newComplex, b.squaredMagnitudeComplex());
    }
```

[Click here to view source](https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinx4/blob/master/sphinx4-core/src/main/java/edu/cmu/sphinx/util/Complex.java#L125)

Comment: I'd stay away from any library with variables named `something1` and `something2`!  Next time just post the actual code (and link) in your question; you'll get a better answer if we know the context.

Comment: @NuriTasdemir Sorry, I've followed your suggestion. See my edit above

Comment: What you have written (in the latest edit) is NOT valid java.  It unhelpful to keep changing the meaning of your Question with a stream of edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the original code and your code is that the original code makes changes to the `Complex` where `divideComplex` is called on, while your code does not change it, because it creates a new local `Complex`.

However, then `scaleComplex` gets called, which overwrites the values of the current object. So the final outcome is indeed identical. But there might be a difference in performance: In your code, a new object is created and discarded, while the original code works in-place without having to allocate new memory. The original version *should* be more efficient regarding memory-usage and performance (I say "*should*", because the JVM optimizer isn't that predictable).